# ArrayList add method is overwriting Objects in the list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

So, when I try adding a Trick to an ArrayList the Trick that is added overwrites what is already in the ArrayList so that all the elements in the ArrayList consists of the trick I have just added.

These methods are in my main class:

```
public Trick playTrick(Player firstPlayer){
     Trick t=new Trick(firstPlayer.getID());
        return t;

}


public void playGame(){

    for(int i=0;i<NOS_TRICKS;i++){

        Trick t=playTrick(players[firstPlayer]);
        players[firstPlayer].update(t);
        //System.out.println(t.completedTricks);
    }

}
```

The error is occurring when players[firstPlayer].update(t) is called, update(t) adds Trick t to my ArrayList:

```
public class BPlayer implents Player{
   public void update(Trick t){
       this.strategy.updateData(t);
   }
}
```

This then triggers updateData:

```
public class AdvStrategy implements Strategy{
    public static ArrayList<Trick> completedTricks = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void updateData(Trick c) {
        completedTricks.add(c);
    }
}
```

Example of my output when printing the ArrayList:

```
Trick ={3=KING DIAMONDS, 0=TWO DIAMONDS, 1=THREE DIAMONDS, 2=FIVE DIAMONDS}
Lead =3 Winner =3 DIAMONDS
ARRAYLIST[{3=KING DIAMONDS, 0=TWO DIAMONDS, 1=THREE DIAMONDS, 2=FIVE DIAMONDS}]
Trick ={3=QUEEN DIAMONDS, 0=FOUR DIAMONDS, 1=SIX DIAMONDS, 2=TEN DIAMONDS}
Lead =3 Winner =3 DIAMONDS
ARRAYLIST[{3=QUEEN DIAMONDS, 0=FOUR DIAMONDS, 1=SIX DIAMONDS, 2=TEN DIAMONDS}, {3=QUEEN DIAMONDS, 0=FOUR DIAMONDS, 1=SIX DIAMONDS, 2=TEN DIAMONDS}]
```

Last line of output should be this when working...

```
ARRAYLIST[{3=KING DIAMONDS, 0=TWO DIAMONDS, 1=THREE DIAMONDS, 2=FIVE DIAMONDS}, {3=QUEEN DIAMONDS, 0=FOUR DIAMONDS, 1=SIX DIAMONDS, 2=TEN DIAMONDS}]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Problem suggests you're reusing an existing trick to set the cards instead of creating a new trick. However, the code responsible for that is not visible in the information provided so far as you seem to be thinking that `ArrayList` is at fault and not your own code.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `Trick t` this is a *reference* to a Trick and when you add this *reference* to an ArrayList, the reference is copied not the object it references.  This means if you add the same reference to a List more than once and you alter the object it references, it appears that all object have changed before there is actually only one.

Somewhere in your code, you are adding the same reference more than once.  I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to see exactly where this happens.

Alternatively you could check whether the Trick you are about to add is already in the list and throw an error if it is.

Comment: Surely this is not the first time in 6+ years someone asks a question which boils down to that problem. Where's the canonical dupe?

Comment: @BalusC indeed though it is not clear from the code provided what is exactly the problem which is why more investigation is needed using their debugger.  If I mark a question as "Did you try to debug that?" I would use it very often.